# Motion planning algorithm

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider a path connected topological space $X$, one can equip its path space $PX=\{ \gamma: [0,1] \longrightarrow X \; continuous\}$ with the compact open topology. We call a ***motion planning algorithm*** of $X$, any continuous section $s:X\times X \longrightarrow PX$ of the evaluation $$ev: PX \longrightarrow X\times X, \; \gamma\mapsto (\gamma(0), \gamma(1))$$
M. Farber has shown that such section exists if and only if $X$ is contractible. Hence, we denote $\mathcal{M}(X)$ the space of such sections.

**Question:** Is $\mathcal{M}(X)$ also contractible when $X$ is contractible?

Any remarks or comments are welcome, thank

Comment: The map $ev : PX \to X\times X$ you give is always a fibration. If $X$ is contractible, $ev$ is also a homotopy equivalence. By a standard result in the theory of fibrations, it follows that $ev$ is a homotopy equivalence over $X\times X$, i.e. there is a section $s$ of $ev$ and a homotopy $H : PX \times I \to PX$ between the identity of $PX$ and $s\circ ev$ such that $ev\circ H$ is a constant homotopy. Finally, the homotopy $(f,t) \mapsto H_t \circ f$ provides a contraction of $\mathcal{M}(X)$. By the way, there is also a completely elementary construction of such a contraction.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: Very clear, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think so, assuming that $X$ is a CW-complex, of course. The evaluation map is a fibration, and $\mathcal M(X)$ is the fiber of the following fibration between mapping spaces
$$\operatorname{map}(X\times X,PX)\longrightarrow \operatorname{map}(X\times X,X\times X)$$
at the identity in $X\times X$. Since $X\times X$ is contractible, then so is the target mapping space, therefore the fiber is weakly equivalent to the source, which is also contractible since $PX\simeq X\simeq *$.

Comment: Thanks Pr. Muro, but what about the case if $X$ is not CW-complex?

Comment: Then you can say noting, but what non-CW-example would be interesting for you?

Comment: what non-CW-example would be interesting? That's another kind of question I guess. Thanks so much for your reactivity

Comment: Probably none..

Comment: Why do you need a CW complex?

Comment: @JeffStrom So that the claimed fibrations are indeed fibrations, maybe? I don't know if all this works in a bigger generality, but you're the right person to answer this!

Comment: $ev$ should be a fibration as long as $* \to X$ is a cofibration.

Comment: @JeffStrom what do you mean by $*\rightarrow X$? This is an unbased context, I think. And if $X$ were based, I can't see the relation with $ev$.

Comment: Sorry!  $i:\partial I \hookrightarrow I$ is an unpointed cofibration so $i^*=ev$ is a fibration.

Comment: Ah, that's good. Is that fibration preserved by taking mapping spaces out of $X\times X$ for any $X$?

Comment: **A naive question**: before to ask if $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is contractible or not, we must equip it with a topology. So $\mathcal{M}(X)$ inherits canonically any topology from that of $X$?

Comment: @FernandoMuro: From your answer, one can conclude that $\mathcal M(X)$ is weakly contractible. But why $\mathcal M(X)$ is contractible? is it, for example, a CW-complex, which allows us to conclude that is contractible.